# Start Activity inside onReceive BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I created some custom notifications with 2 pendingintents.
After triggering one of them, I want to start the MainActivity in the onReceive() method.
But none of those 7 versions of the code is working.

I'm using Kotlin, and I'm testing on SDK version 32(emulator) and 33.

```
    class switchButtonListener : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

        val selectedcat = intent?.action
        var idToIdentify = selectedcat!!.split("|")[1]

        if (selectedcat!!.contains("recatIntent")){
            //TestKotlinConstantClass.suggestedCategory = "Ungeplant"
            //overtake value from notification, open fragment0, insert value
            val database2 = SampleSQLiteDBHelperNotCategorized(context).writableDatabase
            val cursorClickedEntry: Cursor = database2.rawQuery(
                "select _id ,amount, date from expenses_notcat where _id ='"+idToIdentify.toString()+"'",
                null
            )

            var manualInputValue = ""
            var entryId = ""
            if (cursorClickedEntry.moveToFirst()) {
                entryId = cursorClickedEntry.getString(0)
                manualInputValue = cursorClickedEntry.getString(1)
                cursorClickedEntry.close()
            }



            TestKotlinConstantClass.acceptedValue = manualInputValue
            that.cancel(SUGGCAT, entryId.toInt())
            if (TestKotlinConstantClass.acceptedValue != "") {

                //version 0
                //val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
                //intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK;
                //context?.startActivity(intent)

                // version 1
                //val i = Intent()
                //i.setClassName("com.example.myapplication", "com.example.myapplication.MainActivity")
                //i.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                //context!!.startActivity(i)
                //context!!.applicationContext.startActivity(i)

                // version 2
                val intentone = Intent(context!!.applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
                intentone.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                context!!.startActivity(intentone)

                // version 3
                //val intent1 = Intent()
                //intent1.setClassName(contex!!.packageName, MainActivity::class.java.name)
                //intent1.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                //context!!.startActivity(intent1)

                //version 4
                //val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
                //intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                //context!!.startActivity(intent)

                //version 5
                //val cName = ComponentName("com.example.myapplication", "com.example.myapplication.MainActivity")
                //val intent = Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN")
                //intent.component = cName
                //intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

                //version 6
                //val intent = context!!.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.myapplication")
                //intent!!.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                //context!!.startActivity(intent)

                //version 7
                //val intent: Intent = context!!.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName())!!
                //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
                //context!!.startActivity(i)
            }
        }
        else if (selectedcat!!.contains("goneIntent")){
            //remove notification
            // get entryid
            val database2 = SampleSQLiteDBHelperNotCategorized(context).writableDatabase
            val cursorClickedEntry: Cursor = database2.rawQuery(
                "select _id ,amount, date from expenses_notcat where _id ='"+idToIdentify.toString()+"'",
                null
            )
            var entryId = ""
            if (cursorClickedEntry.moveToFirst()){
                entryId = cursorClickedEntry.getString(0)
                cursorClickedEntry.close()
            }

            val databaseNotCat = SampleSQLiteDBHelperNotCategorized(context).writableDatabase
            databaseNotCat.execSQL("DELETE FROM expenses_notcat WHERE _id='"+ entryId.toString()+"'")

            that.cancel(SUGGCAT, entryId.toInt())
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my entry (NotificationListener$switchButtonListener) in the manifest and also the activity I want to launch:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.myapplication">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <receiver android:name=".NotificationListener$switchButtonListener"></receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".ExampleWidgetService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

If I execute the code of version 0 in some setOnClickListener, the code works perfectly and launches the main activity.
But its not possible for me to launch the main activity within the onreceive()
of BroadcastReceiver.
Most of the time the app is just doing nothing.

When I fill the intent (TestKotlinConstantClass.intent) and context (TestKotlinConstantClass.context) analog the coding in version 0 in some other widget funtion (where I already start different activities without an error) and store them in some helper variables and use those to start the activity in the `onReceive()`, it is working fine.
But it shouldn't be like so, that you have to press some widget button before you will be able to start the acitivty from the notification correctly.

```
TestKotlinConstantClass.context.startActivity(TestKotlinConstantClass.intent)
```

Comment: You cannot start activities from the background in modern versions of Android. Have your `Notification` use an activity `PendingIntent`, rather than a broadcast `PendingIntent`, if you want to start an activity from a `Notification`.

Comment: What you're trying to implement here is a [notification trampoline](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#notification-trampolines) which is not allowed since android 12. Check the logcat, you've probably got trampoline error.